German Visit Visa
I am an international student in the UK. My UK visa expires in October, and I want to travel to Germany in September. Is it possible that I can get my German visa if my itinerary plan is to go back to my country directly from Germany, as I’m planning to stay in Germany till November.
Obviously I can’t go back to the UK after my visit to Germany, because my UK visa expires in October.

What is the question? I cannot parse a obviously I cant come back...please let me know if its possible

What ties to your home country do you have to prove intention to leave Germany?

As long as you have an itinerary that exits the Schengen Area and you can actually enter the destination country (whether because it’s your own country, a country you can enter visa-free, or a country for which you have a visa) and any transit countries on the way, it doesn’t matter where you go after your visit in Germany.
However, one important part of a visa application is to show ties to another country, which serve as an indication that you actually have a reason to leave the country you want to visit in time, rather than overstay, try to live and work there illegally, etc.
Since you won’t be able to say “I will return to the UK to pursue my studies”, you need to give a good reason you actually need to return to your home country.
This is usually something like a job (with a contract, an actual employer, and a salary which is not too low compared to what you could get in Germany working illegally), or further studies (with proof of enrolment).
This is something which can already be difficult in normal circumstances, but the fact that you are switching countries at the same time may make it even more difficult, depending on your circumstances.

How difficult it actually is depends a lot on OP's home country but for most countries where this wouldn't be an issue OP probably wouldn't need a visa to travel to Germany as a tourist. Which is to say, unfortunately it looks like the chance of a visa refusal for Germany for OP are quite high.
